# how can I convert an attribute value of type date to php datetime object in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, catalog-product

I have created in the backend a product attribute called `estimated_date` and I would like to manipulate it in an observer for `catalog_product_save_after`.

So from my `catalog/product` model I would like to

- read this saved date,
- convert it to a `DateTime` object,
- manipulate it (in my case add a few days based on conditions)
- and then save it back to another `Date` attribute.

The value that I get in my observer's product is of the form `13/11/2019` in this case when using `$product->getData('estimated_date')` but I would like to use a safe way to detect the date format used to save the attribute.

Comment: Is the date format used to save the attribute always consistent? I would think it needs to be.

Comment: From my observations the format that the attribute is saved as is always consistent on the database as UTC  Y-m-d H:i:s  However when the observer is pulling the data it's formatting it according to the interface language I pick for example in Greek it's 13/11/2019 and in US English it's 11/13/2019 which means it's taking into account the locale

Comment: I've also tried retrieving the locale of the current store and retrieve the date format for that one then pass it as parameter and it yields something like Y MMM d  but it's not the one that I see